# laravel function permissions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a working function in my controller but I want to add a permissions gate in order to use the function.

Basically, right before the `collect` line in the first section, I want to add `Gate::allows('can-fix', 'testFix') ?: parent::denyAccess();` but I'm testing it and even though I don't have the 'testFix' ability, it still lets me through

I don't want to add a gate at the route level, I want it to actually access the controller method but kick me out if I'm not allowed to do anything in the method itself.

Am I declaring the gate incorrectly here?

```
    public function editCategorySort(categorySur $category, Request $request, $categoryGroup)
    {
        Gate::allows('can-fix', 'testFix') ?: parent::denyAccess();
        collect($request->input('sur'))
            ->each(function ($asset) use ($categoryGroup, $category) {
                $data = [
                    'category_sur' => $asset['category_sur'],
                    'type' => $asset['type'],
                ];
                $category_sur_id = $asset['id'];
                $category->updateCategoryGroup($categoryGroup, $category_sur_id, $data);
            });
    }
```

Comment: can you share gate declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you defined your gate, but the code below works for me.

`controller`

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    Gate::allows('can-fix') ?: dd('you do not have the access');

    dd('yes you can reach here');
});
```

`app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php`

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('can-fix', fn () => true);
    }
```

so if `fn () => true` the result is `"yes you can reach here"`
if `fn () => false` the result is `"you do not have the access"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this works, but is there a way to just use the gate in a function without the route?

Comment: @TomN. I think the answer is yes(have not tested though), `Gate` is just `laravel facades` you can use it anywhere. It uses `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php` under the hood. So you should be able to use it anywhere.